# Degree of a vertex x of a graph G in its line graph L(G)

Tags: graph-theory

According to Frank Harary's book on Graph Theory, we have the following:

For a graph G with vertex x joining two edges u and v, i.e. x=uv , we have degree of x in the line graph L(G) is given by
deg (x) = deg (u) + deg (v) - 2

My question is will this formula work on graphs with loops?

Can someone please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: It is not a very mysterious formula; you can see where it comes from just by looking at the definition of the line graph, and counting adjacencies. The more important questions, which *you* should answer, are: (1) how do you define the degree of a vertex with loops on it? (2) how do you define the line graph of a graph with loops?

Comment: At the very least, you *can* make those definitions so that the formula continues to hold, if that is important to you.